# Windows 8 incompaitbility with sysinternals Desktops utility

Tags: windows-8, internals, sysinternals

After Googling for about the past hour and a half, I have been unable to find out any definitive information on how the start menu and how windows 8 style applications work behind the scenes.  I was under the impression that Windows 8 Style applications were processes which created fullscreen windows and that the Windows 8 start menu was created by explorer.exe in much the same way.  But there are incompatibilities between Windows 8 the 1.x version Sysinternal's Desktops utility, I have to imagine that something more complex is going on.

However, in Spy++, each Windows 8 style application appears as standard Window with the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` style set, which would make sense, assuming they are nothing special.  With respect to the Start Menu, it appears as a window of class `ImmersiveLauncher` created by `explorer.exe`.  Perhaps explorer has developed an aversion to having multiple instances...

Using the old version of SysInternal's Desktops, the explorer instances in the additional desktops work fine, but do not load pinned items nor load the desktop background and icons.

Is there any documentation on why Windows 8 behaves differently from past versions when multiple copies of `explorer.exe` are running in different desktops?

(This is purely for curiosity's sake)

(Yes, I know there is a [Desktops 2.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) version available which supports Windows 8, but it uses interesting workarounds, like switching to the original desktop when the windows key is pressed.  It also seems to trigger some initialization within explorer.exe when the desktop is loaded for the first time beyond simply starting the process.)

Comment: Even the Desktops 2.0 upgrade doesn't work properly on Windows 8.1. Any fixes?

Comment: @tMJ, it doesn't outright fail.  If you use the windows key on your keyboard the start screen will still come up as it should.

Comment: Pressing the windows key, although take me to the start screen but it does so by shifting me to Desktop 1.

Comment: @tMJ, That is by design, and is the behavior introduced in Desktops 2.0 with Windows 8.  In fact, I actually mentioned that behavior in the question.

Comment: I emailed Mark Russinovich about incompatibility between Desktops v2 & Win 8 (first in Q1 2013); but have not heard back.
In addition to the issues you mentioned, some applications like Google Chrome appear to have an aversion to having multiple instances open on different desktops, in v2. Desktops is still very useful to me in Windows 8 (in v2 you can still start most applications from pinned shortcuts on the taskbar, or from desktop shortcuts etc.) It would be a wonderful native "out-of-the-box" power-user feature for Windows...
(MS granted my wish: this feature is reportedly in Win 10!)